# Display top level category for each product in emails as well as order pages (backend)

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to display the top level category for each product in emails sent to customers and on the order pages in the backend. I was able to get it to show all categories, but I need it to show only the top level.

This is what I need to show all categories:

```
// Display categories in emails
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'display_custom_data_in_emails', 10, 4 );
function display_custom_data_in_emails( $item_id, $item, $order, $bool ) {
    
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

    echo "<br><small>" . implode(', ', $terms) . "</small>";
}


// Display categories in admin order pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'custom_admin_order_itemmeta', 15, 3 );
function custom_admin_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $item, $product ){
   
    if( $item->is_type( 'line_item' ) ){
        
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

        echo "<br><small>" . implode(', ', $terms) . "</small>";
    }
}
```